# How can i make my REST API Faster with nodejs and express?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

1. Summarize the problem

My problem: I have built a slow API. I want to make my api faster.

I am using Node.js and express to make REST APIs.
And I have one api that takes average response time of 3.5s.

Below is what it does.

1. It gets all userIds.
2. Based on the userIds, it requests parallel REST APIs to get other user Data such as projectIds and groupIds. (Since the databases are in different DB, it is inevitable to make different Rest APIs)
3. Based on the userData(userId, projectId, groupId etc..), it filters. ex) projectId = 1.
4. It requests 4 different REST APIs in parallel such as schedule and timezone and so on.

I believe I am making two many requests because if there is 10 accounts. I am making 54 requests in total to response.

I want to get whole DB table with each request and combine them with code.
Help me there is better way to do it.

Thx in advance.

Comment: you cant get around make a query per database, but you can get around making those queries for each user. Consider grouping the requests.

Comment: I would say bad application design. Rethink your application and eliminate that thousend requests hell. A bad application is a bad application. No matter what its written in.

Comment: I guess its more about design than code itself. Thank you for the feedbacks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following ways to decrease the response time.

1. Use logging to find which query takes most of the time and optimize it.
2. Using Redis. Use caching to handle frequent common requests. Caching will
   remove the need to make any additional queries.
3. Make sure all the requests and queries inside are actually async and
   try to make a common Database or Table to Get this data instead of various
   databases.

Comment: I guess I need a new table ready for the request. I considered using redis but it seems having a table would solve the problem. Thx!